# sharing DTO classes between server and client impossible because of EntityData : ITableData

Tags: azure-mobile-services

I share a Data Transfer Object between an C# Azure Mobile Services server and client. I use the same class in both applications.

The TableController class used by Azure mobile services requires the DTO to inherit from 'EntityData', which in turn implements interface 'ITableData'.

ITable Data lives is part of reference:

> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Service.Tables

I have not figured out how to include that reference without installing the entire server-side mobile services package in nuget:

> WindowsAzureMobileServices.Backend

That includes OWIN, and many other references the client does not need. This is what I am doing currently. This works for a desktop application I am currently working on, but I think it will not work for universal apps and windows phone apps.

I also looked at microsoft's samples for mobile services, and there they use separate classes as DTOS for server and client.

Is it really the case that we have to write the same code twice?

Comment: this is why you should separate your data layer from your code

Comment: I don't understand your comment, this is a DTO, it IS the data

Comment: the data plus some bumf about how to save it server side it appears

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but you could better make use of Shared Projects, and partial classes.
Your Shared Project will have common properties for the entities.
Other projects will reference this Shared one, and can add some other properties to shared entities, still using partial classes.

I have precise experience with AMS, so I know what you are meaning.
In my experience, is anyway not realistic to think to have exactly the same entity classes for client and server.
For instance, in so called Portable Class Libraries you can have a very small subset of framework, and references available.
Other than properties, you normally put attributes on POCO class files. On the client you may have some attributes that aren't available/meaningful for the server (e.g. SQLite attributes), or viceversa. You may can get stuck in this situation also with the shared projects approach I suggest, but it could be managed there with what so called preprocessor directives.

Comment: Just to add on it. I think in the case that the client use a small subset of the DTO class, he could probably use automapper. For example, the web project consumes more than a mobile app. But to be honest, sometimes figuring out the mapping is probably more headache than just writing the "partial" class twice.